# In definitions, I need a specific method signature only if generic type is an array

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, typescript-generics

Here is a slightly simplified version of the definitions for Knockout's `subscribable`:

```js
export type SubscriptionCallback<T = any, TTarget = void> = (this: TTarget, val: T) => void;

export interface Subscription {
    dispose(): void;
}

export interface SubscribableFunctions<T = any> extends Function {
    init<S extends Subscribable<any>>(instance: S): void;

    notifySubscribers(valueToWrite?: T, event?: string): void;

    // This definition is wrong
    subscribe<TTarget = void>(callback: SubscriptionCallback<Array<ArrayChange<T>>, TTarget>, callbackTarget: TTarget, event: "arrayChange"): Subscription;

    subscribe<TTarget = void>(callback: SubscriptionCallback<T, TTarget>, callbackTarget?: TTarget, event?: "change"): Subscription;
    subscribe<X = any, TTarget = void>(callback: SubscriptionCallback<X, TTarget>, callbackTarget: TTarget, event: string): Subscription;

    extend(requestedExtenders: ObservableExtenderOptions): this;
    extend<S extends Subscribable<any>>(requestedExtenders: ObservableExtenderOptions): S;

    getSubscriptionsCount(event?: string): number;
}

export interface Subscribable<T = any> extends SubscribableFunctions<T> { }

export interface ArrayChange<T = any> {
    status: "added" | "deleted" | "retained";
    value: T;
    index: number;
    moved?: number;
}
```

The problem is that the definition of the callback for the `arrayChange` event is wrong. First the `arrayChange` event should only apply if `T` is an array, say `X[]`. Then, the value used by the `ArrayChange` interface needs to be the `X` type and not `X[]`.

How can I include the `arrayChange` event signature only if `T` is an array and be able to extract the underlying type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to extract the item from an array. To restrict the availability of the overload for arrays to only when the `T` type is an array we can add a type annotation for the `this` parameter. The method will only be available if the call target conforms to the constraint imposed by the `this` parameter type.

```
export type SubscriptionCallback<T = any, TTarget = void> = (this: TTarget, val: T) => void;

export interface Subscription {
    dispose(): void;
}

// The conditional type that extracts the array item if T is an array
type ItemIfArray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;

export interface SubscribableFunctions<T = any> extends Function {
    init<S extends Subscribable<any>>(instance: S): void;

    notifySubscribers(valueToWrite?: T, event?: string): void;

    // this must be something compatible with  SubscribableFunctions<any[]> which should mean a SubscribableFunctions where T is an array 
    subscribe<TTarget = void>(this: SubscribableFunctions<any[]>, callback: SubscriptionCallback<Array<ArrayChange<ItemIfArray<T>>>, TTarget>, callbackTarget: TTarget, event: "arrayChange"): Subscription;

    subscribe<TTarget = void>(callback: SubscriptionCallback<T, TTarget>, callbackTarget?: TTarget, event?: "change"): Subscription;
     // since the last overload has the event of type string it allows invocation with arrayChange so I removed it to get the error below, not 100% sure if keeping this overload is a good idea. 
    //subscribe<X = any, TTarget = void>(callback: SubscriptionCallback<X, TTarget>, callbackTarget: TTarget, event: string): Subscription;
    getSubscriptionsCount(event?: string): number;
}

export interface Subscribable<T = any> extends SubscribableFunctions<T> { }

export interface ArrayChange<T = any> {
    status: "added" | "deleted" | "retained";
    value: T;
    index: number;
    moved?: number;
}

let a: Subscribable<number>
a.subscribe(() => { }, void 0, 'arrayChange') //err overload not available for this type parameter 


let ar: Subscribable<number[]>
ar.subscribe(a => a[0].value.toExponential() , void 0, 'arrayChange') //ok
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer definitely works. Your technique of setting the `this` type got me thinking that maybe it could be simplified. I was able to get the same result using `subscribe<U = never, TTarget = void>(this: SubscribableFunctions<U[]>, callback: SubscriptionCallback<ArrayChange<U>[], TTarget>, callbackTarget: TTarget, event: "arrayChange"): Subscription;`

Comment: @MichaelBest That also works, it was actually my first instinct  to do it that way you describe, but I was not sure how common it way to specify `TTarget` as an explicit type parameter. If you add the extra parameter callers wanting to specify one of the type parameters will have to specify both (partial inference is not possible in TS). But either way works

Comment: Reading over the docs for [`infer`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/03/15/announcing-typescript-2-8-rc/), I realized that I really just need to "flatten" the type because the `arrayChange` event can support non-array types, which will just be treated as a single-item array. So I'll remove the condition on `this` and then use this type: `type Flatten<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;`

Comment: @MichaelBest if the `arrayChange` event is valid if  `T` does not extends `any[]` then yes the condition on `this` is not necessary and `Flatten` will do just what you want it to do. Your question made it appear that the event was only available if T was an array.